# Android MediaCodec: eglSwapBuffers: EGL error: 0x300d

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, android-mediacodec, egl, mediamuxer

So the problem only occurs when I try and record for the second time. Meaning the first time I run the MediaCodecs and Muxer everything works most of the time. But now I want the app to be more stable.

Help figure out what is not being torn down and setup correctly.

Basically on the second run, everything setup fine, but when 'Renderer.drawFrame' calls `GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` I get the error: `I/Adreno﹕ Native window GetBuffer failed`

And when `GLES20.glFlush();` is called the error is: `I/Adreno﹕ Failed to acquire a surface`

Which always precedes the `eglSwapBuffers: EGL error: 0x300d` when I try swapping the buffers. So something isn't getting cleaned up from the first run.

Clean Up code:

```
    public void releaseCapture(){
    if (audioCodec != null){
        audioCodec.stop();
        audioCodec = null;
    }
    if (videoCodec != null){
        videoCodec.stop();
        videoCodec = null;
    }
    if (mediaMux != null){
        mediaMux.release();
        mediaMux = null;
    }
    if ( releaseAll ) {
        releaseAll = false;
        //releaseSurfaceTexture();
        mEGLWrapper.destroySurface();
    }
}
```

MyMediaCodec.stop()

```
public void stop(){
    if (codec == null) return; 
    if (!isAudioCodec) {
        videoCodecInputSurface.release();
    }
    codecPrimed=false;
    codec.stop();
    codec.release();
    codec = null;
    codecManager.stopMuxer(isAudioCodec);
}
```

MyMediaMuxer.stop()

```
    public void stopMuxer(boolean isAudio){
    if (mediaMux == null) return;
    if (isAudio){
        audioActive = false;
    } else {
        videoActive = false;
    }
    if (!(audioActive||videoActive)){
        Log.d(TAG, "Stopping Muxer now. audio frame count = " + audioFrameCount +
                "; video frame count = " + videoFrameCount);
        videoHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mediaMux!=null) mediaMux.stop();
                // set up for next run
                releaseCapture();
            }

        },frame_delay);
    }
}
```

mEGLWrapper.destroySurface();

```
public void destroySurface(){
    EGL14.eglDestroySurface(mEGLDisplay,mEGLSurface);
    checkEglError("eglDestroySurace");
}
```

Errorlog

```
05-05 17:51:43.072  27756-27913/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree 

E/OMXMaster﹕ A component of name 'OMX.qcom.audio.decoder.aac' already exists, ignoring this one.
05-05 17:51:43.085  27756-27918/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree I/OMXClient﹕ Using client-side OMX mux.
05-05 17:51:43.470  27756-27756/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree D/penny.cam.MyMediaCodec﹕ Camera profile: Frame Rate = 30; Bit Rate = 42000000
05-05 17:51:43.470  27756-27756/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree D/penny.cam.MyMediaCodec﹕ ; Heighth = 2160; Width = 3840
05-05 17:51:43.472  27756-27918/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree E/ACodec﹕ [OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] storeMetaDataInBuffers (output) failed w/ err -1010
05-05 17:51:43.474  27756-27918/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree W/ACodec﹕ do not know color format 0x7fa30c04 = 2141391876
05-05 17:51:43.475  27756-27918/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree W/ACodec﹕ do not know color format 0x7f000789 = 2130708361
05-05 17:51:43.478  27756-27918/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree I/ACodec﹕ setupVideoEncoder succeeded
05-05 17:51:43.478  27756-27918/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree W/ACodec﹕ do not know color format 0x7f000789 = 2130708361
05-05 17:52:57.317  27756-27784/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree I/Adreno﹕ Native window GetBuffer failed
05-05 17:55:41.518  27756-27784/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree I/Adreno﹕ Failed to acquire a surface
05-05 17:56:24.246  27756-27791/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree V/com.hpp.MyMediaMux﹕ Trying to write data before muxer started, isAudioSample = true
05-05 18:04:55.189  27756-27784/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree D/io.hpp.MyGLSurfaceView18﹕ eglSwapBuffers: EGL error: 0x300d
05-05 18:04:55.189  27756-27784/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree W/System.err﹕ java.lang.Exception
05-05 18:04:55.189  27756-27784/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree W/System.err﹕ at com.hpp.openGL.MyEGLWrapper.checkEglError(MyEGLWrapper.java:443)
05-05 18:04:55.190  27756-27784/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree W/System.err﹕ at com.hpp.openGL.MyEGLWrapper.swapBuffers(MyEGLWrapper.java:314)
05-05 18:04:55.190  27756-27784/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree W/System.err﹕ at com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.camera.CaptureManager.drawFrame(CaptureManager.java:478)
05-05 18:04:55.190  27756-27784/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree W/System.err﹕ at com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.camera.CaptureManager.drawFrameOnInputSurface(CaptureManager.java:463)
05-05 18:04:55.190  27756-27784/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree W/System.err﹕ at com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.camera.CaptureManager.videoCaptureLoop(CaptureManager.java:335)
05-05 18:04:55.190  27756-27784/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree W/System.err﹕ at com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.camera.CaptureManager$5.run(CaptureManager.java:318)
05-05 18:04:55.190  27756-27784/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree W/System.err﹕ at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1462)
05-05 18:04:55.190  27756-27784/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree W/System.err﹕ at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sweet, I got it shortly after posting this. One `EGL14.eglDestroySurface(mEGLDisplay,mEGLSurface);` does not set mEGLSurface to `EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE` like I assumed. And you wouldn't know it because I didn't post it, but MyEGLWrapper.makeCurrent() checks for this:

```
    public void makeCurrent(boolean toScreen, Surface surface) {
    if (toScreen) { //as opposed to toEncoder
        makeScreenSurfaceCurrent();
        return;
    } 
    if (mEGLSurface.equals(EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE)){

        mEGLSurface = EGL14.eglCreateWindowSurface(mEGLDisplay, configs[0], surface,
                surfaceAttribs, 0);
        checkEglError("eglCreateWindowSurface");
    }
    EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(mEGLDisplay, mEGLSurface, mEGLSurface, mEGLContext);
    checkEglError("eglMakeCurrent");
}
```

and two, releaseAll was set to false so mEGLSurface was not even getting destroyed...

thanks for looking.